An animated romantic movie in space about soldiers
I saw a Sci-Fi space adventure animation movie (English dubbed probably) in  February-March 2008.
The movie was in space, where humans (soldiers) fight against an evil guy from another planet. The romance builds up between two soldiers (the good ones), while they fight to save their planet/spaceship.
The movie had a character pree-aa-rious (that's how it was pronounced).
I forgot the entire plot, but there was this one dialogue which goes "Pree-aa-rious no matter what i'll be there for you till the end of the world"
I have been searching for this movie for the past 1 year or so. Though I couldn't give much details, it will be great if someone could just help me here.

Fairly certain I know what you're after, but more details will definitely help: Was the movie recent in 2008? Where did you see it? What was the animation style like? And are you sure you remember nothing about the plot? Not even what kind of characters, creatures, vehicles, items etc. were in it?

Wow! thanks for commenting. Well i saw the movie somewhere in February-March 2008. As i said i forgot the plot. But the movie was in space, where humans(soldiers) fight against a evil guy from another planet. The romance builds up between two soldiers (the good ones), while they fight to save their planet/spaceship.
I know that's not enough but i really liked the romantic angle.(I'm not a fan of Romantic movies, but the feelings/dialogues were good thus this desperation :| ) . Thanks again for taking your time and commenting.

Sounds like the Appleseed franchise, most likely Appleseed Ex Machina from 2007.

When a paramilitary task force called E.S.W.A.T. and its operations in the year 2133 Olympus, a futuristic utopia where humans, cyborgs, and bio-engineered human beings called "Bioroids" are attempting to live in perfect harmony. However, a series of random terrorist attacks perpetrated by cyborgs and humans alike threaten to throw Olympus into total chaos. As it turns out, these humans and machines have come under the influence of an unknown electronic signal that hacks into their nervous systems and they then become the unwilling servants of a malevolent computerized entity. Thrown into the action is the plucky female E.S.W.A.T. warrior Deunan Knute and her cyborg lover/partner Briareos as they investigate these bizarre occurrences with the other members of their unit.

Near the end, Deunan tells Briareos:

I'll always protect you, even if the world comes to an end.

It's a sequel to Appleseed from 2004 and I'm pretty sure she's referencing something he told her there. There's also an old OVA from 1988. Here's the trailer:




Awesome!!
I think that's the one.. 'Briareos' is the name. :)
Thank you very much,
(though all my details were incorrect, u still managed to identify it)

@Lil'DexT3r Was this the right film in the end?

Yes, Walt it was the film I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Is the movie wall-e
It's animation plus Romance and space too 
Here is the IMDb walle

Is there something wrong with answer??

Hi JigarGandhi. I'm assuming your answer was downvoted for 2 reasons: 1. It's very brief. It's best to elaborate and at least detail the plot of the suggested film (or paste a synopsis). 2. It looks like a guess or a suggestion, not an answer based on concrete evidence, since there are arguably many movies that fit those particular genres. Note that the OP mentioned more specific details like a certain character's name and a certain sentence, and neither of them exist in Wall-e.
